# How to express difference of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Suppose I have two sets, $A$ and $B$. Now, which method is more appropriate to express the difference of sets? See below:-

$A - B$ or,

$A\setminus B$

If there's any problem in my question please inform me. Thanks!

Comment: How about… [Google](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement)?

Comment: @AndréLevy Sorry, my bad

Comment: There is also $A\smallsetminus B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A\setminus B$ is fully standard. $A-B$ is also widely used, but bears the risk of ambiguity in some contexts as it could also stand for $\{\,a-b\mid a\in A,b\in B\,\}$

Comment: One argument is that : $A-B$ is easier to write in LaTeX.

Comment: $\def\-{\setminus}$`\def\-{\setminus}` makes it *not so much* harder to write $A\-B$

Answer (score 0):

In general the second notation is the less ambiguous. In some contexts $A-B$ can also mean

$$
A-B:=\{a-b \mid a \in A, \ b \in B\}
$$